# Sort for plotting data (julia+pyplot)

Tags: sorting, matplotlib, julia

Consider the following simple code

```
using PyPlot
x = [2,5,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]
plot(x,y,".-")
```

As you note the lines that connect the points on the graph are displayed according to the order of the data into the arrays. I mean, the first "point x-y" (2,1) is connected to the point (5,2), that is connected to (3,3) and so on.

[image: disorderplot]

How do I get a graph that reflects this piece of code:

```
using PyPlot
x = [2,3,4,5]
y = [1,3,4,2]
plot(x,y,".-")
```

[image: sortedplot] ?

Or in other words, how can I sort the x-array and preserve the x-y correspondence?

Comment: Try `ind = sortperm(x)` and then plotting `x[ind]` against `y[ind]` should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @jverzani . It works. Feel free to put it as the answer.